# Multiple React-dnd jest tests "Cannot have two HTML5 backends at the same time"

Tags: react-dnd

I have a jest test file with a number of tests in it.

```
import React from 'react';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import HTML5Backend from "react-dnd-html5-backend";
import {DragDropContextProvider} from "react-dnd";

describe('My Component Tests', () => {
    let mockStore;
    let store;

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockStore = configureStore();
        store = mockStore(mockData);
    });

    test(' test1', () => {
        const cmpt = <Provider store={store}>
            <DragDropContextProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
                <MyComponent state={1}/>
            </DragDropContextProvider>
        </Provider>;

        const tree = renderer.create(cmpt).toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    test(' test2', () => {
        const cmpt = <Provider store={store}>
            <DragDropContextProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
                <MyComponent state={2}/>
            </DragDropContextProvider>
        </Provider>;

        const tree = renderer.create(cmpt).toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

The first test always work

But the subsequent ones always come up with this error :

```
 Error: Uncaught [Error: Cannot have two HTML5 backends at the same time.]
```

I am guessing this is because the HTMLBackend is treated as a singleton, and is used across tests which is not what I want. I want tests which run independantly.

Is there some was of creating an instance of the HTMLBackend in the **beforeEach()** function.

I have tried to encapsule the HTML5Backend into a singleton, but I get the same Problem :

```
let html5Backend = null;

function getSingleton() {
    if (!html5Backend) {
        html5Backend = HTML5Backend;
        debugger;
    }
    return html5Backend;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by referencing HTMLBackend instance in the "describe" level, like so :

```
describe('My Component Tests', () => {
    let mockStore;
    let store;

    let htmlbe = HTML5Backend; //reference instance here!!!

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockStore = configureStore();
        store = mockStore(mockData);
    });

    test(' test1', () => {
        const cmpt = <Provider store={store}>
            <DragDropContextProvider backend={htmlbe }>
                <MyComponent state={1}/>
            </DragDropContextProvider>
        </Provider>;

        const tree = renderer.create(cmpt).toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    test(' test2', () => {
        const cmpt = <Provider store={store}>
            <DragDropContextProvider backend={htmlbe }>
                <MyComponent state={2}/>
            </DragDropContextProvider>
        </Provider>;

        const tree = renderer.create(cmpt).toJSON();
```

This is the equivalent of having a singleton across all tests.

Comment: actually I think i was premature with this answer :( This doesn't seem to work properly

Comment: Just curious, if you split test1 and test2 into separate files will it work?

Comment: Maybe it has to do the Jest scoping ( https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown )